# concat single comma with string using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

my function java script **showPartialView**,has 4 parameters as following

**controller** ,**action name** ,then  **title** and Finally **ID** .

```
  function() showPartialView(controller,action,title,ID)
        {
        var data ="{"Title":title+","+"id":ID}"  
        $.ajax({
        "URL":controller/action,
        data:json.parse(data)
       })
       }
```

when i call function like that

```
showPartialView("home","index",'test page',28)
```

my variable **data** will be like that

**{"Title":'test page'",id":28}**
but i want it to be

**{"Title":'test page',"id":28}**

Comment: ` function() showPartialView` is invalid Javascript, can you post your *actual* function? A string is a string, `title` shouldn't get enclosed in additional quotes unless the parameter has quotes as well.

Comment: Also the quotes don't work (that's why the syntax highlighting is messed up). And why do you build JSON from the parameters to then parse it as an object? O.o

Comment: fix it function showPartialView(controller,action,title,ID){...}

Comment: If you really need the keys `Title` and `id`, you can just name the parameters the same way (`function showPartialView(controller, action, Title, id)`) and set `data` as `{Title, id}`. You don’t need the additional `data` variable. Also, `controller/action` is not how you construct a string. The `URL` property should be all lower-case. If you really want to parse JSON, it’s `JSON`, not `json`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `var data ="{Title:'" + title + "',id:" + ID+ "}";`. You have incorrect concatenation inside yor function `showPartialView` and that function declaration is also wrong. Correct that and use this,

```js
function showPartialView(controller,action,title,ID){  
  var data ="{\"Title\":'" + title + "',\"id\":" + ID+ "}";
  console.log(data);
}


showPartialView("home","index",'test page',28);
```

Comment: No TO doesn't need different quotes because the construct is completely unnecessary... TO constructs JSON to then parse it into an object which is then passed to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: This is going to fail if `ID` or `title` contains a `"`

Comment: @ben I just moved on with what OP has tried with his code rather that making a entirely new object and then stringifying it. I could have done that put I kept the OP's code in most possible way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a valid json output...
So you could do :

```js
function showPartialView(controller, action, title, ID) {
  var data = '{"Title":"'+title+'", "id":"' + ID + '"}';
  console.log(data)
}

showPartialView("home","index",'test page',28)
```

But that's not bullet proof... if `ID` our `title` contains a `"`, it will fail...

A better approach is to use `JSON.stringify` :

```js
    function showPartialView(controller, action, title, ID) {
      var data = {
        Title: title,
        id: ID
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    showPartialView("home","index",'test page',28)
```

But eventually you don't need all of that because you parse again the object in the `$.ajax`... So just use the plain object:

```js
function showPartialView(controller, action, title, ID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: controller + '/' + action,
    data: {
      Title: title,
      id: ID
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This.  `JSON.stringify` is a much better option than manual JSON.